# Convert wide to long data format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of the following form:

```
 ID  col1  col2  col3 

 a   0     1     0    

 b   1     0     0    

 c   1     0     0
```

I want to transform it in the following form:

```
 ID  value 

 a   col2  
 b   col1  
 c   col1
```

Comment: What if there are two `1`s in one row?

Comment: For now, it's just restricted to this, but I would guess we can split it into two columns of value1 and valu2

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078951/decode-one-hot-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: it isn't duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for n cols for each ID**

```
df2 = df.melt('ID', var_name='value', value_name='n').loc[lambda df: df['n'].eq(1)]
new_df = df2.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                         columns=df2.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1),
                         values=['value'], aggfunc='first')
new_df = (new_df.set_axis([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in new_df.columns], axis=1)
                .reset_index())
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  ID value1
0  a   col2
1  b   col1
2  c   col1
```

---

Another sample

```
ID  col1  col2  col3 

 a   0     1     0    

 b   1     1     0    

 c   1     0     1
```

**Output**

```
  ID value1 value2
0  a   col2    NaN
1  b   col1   col2
2  c   col1   col3
```

Comment: Hi ansev, it works fine, except, the last line gives an error (but still transforms the dataset as intended)

Comment: what line??????

Comment: new_df = (new_df.set_axis([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in new_df.columns], axis=1)
                .reset_index())

Comment: I got the following error: 
  File "<ipython-input-5-7a19bd4d4013>", line 4, in <module>
    new_df = (new_df.set_axis([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in new_df.columns], axis=1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: Have you done inplace=True? You should let inplace=False always

Comment: Where should I change this parameter?

Comment: it is False by default, Y don't understand why `set_axis()` return None but you could do: `new_df.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in new_df. columnas]` and then `new_df = new_df.reset_index()`